# What is meaning of “concert” in this musical theatre score?

Tags: theory, sheet-music, musical-theatre

In rehearsals for a production of American Idiot musical and this reference to “concert” is in the score. My guess is this means male parts should sing in the written concert pitch instead of an octave below, but I am not sure.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 10):

You made a logical assumption, I can’t imagine what else it could mean other than concert pitch. Sometimes scores for musical theater are reductions and/or are written to be as practical as possible for a conductor or piano/conductor. Ask one of the vocalists if you can have a peek at his book, that should give you a definitive answer.

Answer (score 8):

There are men and women singing each of these parts. Normally men singing parts in treble clef sound an octave lower than written. In this case **all** of the parts (men and women) are to sound the written pitches.

Comment: Not to be overly gender-sensitive, but the precise musical terms would be soprano, alto, tenor (or bari), bass parts.  I do know alto males and tenor females.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft The example is from a musical where the SATB terminology is rarely used. But the whole point here is that everybody has to song the same notes, irrespective of gender.

Comment: point taken, tho'  while musicals and operas identify singers by character names, one hopes that the audition process has selected performers based on the designated singing range required of their character  :-)

Answer (score 1):

Green Day didn't go in much for mellow baritone singing. Yes, concert pitch. This is the high tenor 'rock screech'.  I hope your boys know how to do it, or there'll more sore throats than a 'flu epidemic.